# Axis can't validate webservice certificate

Tags: https, certificate, axis

I have to connect to webservice using https. Service have valid certificate issued by GeoTrust Global CA. Whole certification chain looks like this:
[image]

When I run app with

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

parameter, and I sese Global CA on trusted list:

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x23456
  Valid from Tue May 21 06:00:00 CEST 2002 until Sat May 21 06:00:00 CEST 2022
```

but still I'm receiving error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Why axis doesn't verify whole certification chain for webservice over https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone had similar problem:
The problem was with server configuration - appears that server wasn't send whole certification chain(not sure how exactly it's configured), so certificate couldn't be validated. We have verified certificate on ssl checker sites, and reported problem to server administration. After administrators fixed server configuration everything works like a charm!